# Two basic questions about absolute path

Tags: c#, absolute-path

1. How do I get the absolute path of files in the embedded Resource?
2. If I store my images in a folder and use an absolute path to access them, I cannot find them after I build the solution, right?(because the built solution does not have the environment with its development environment)

Comment: An *embedded* resource is embedded in the app exe which is why they are referred to as *embedded*.

Comment: You should come here for questions after you've tried something and are stuck. For example, your second question should read something like: *"I've stored images in a folder and am trying to access them through code using an absolute path, but am unable to find them. How can I access the file system to get the images I have stored? Here's my code: `// some code here`."*

Comment: @RufusL it is not. That one is about the "resources" in the entire project. but I am asking about the file in the resources.

Comment: @RufusL actually, I tried many ways from internet, but they are not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. A file inside an embedded resource doesn't really have an absolute path, since it's contained within your application.
   I assume you're looking for a way to access these files, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3314213/2149093) might be useful.
2. You could modify the "Copy to output directory"-property of your images to have them copied to the bin-folder, but this may not be what you want. Then you could use Reflection to get access to the file, though I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way:

```cs
var executingAssemblyPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(executingAssemblyPath);
var imagePath = Path.Combine(directory, "image.gif");
```

There are 2 alternatives to [Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly(v=vs.110).aspx), which might be more robust depending on your deployment environment:

- [Process.GetCurrentProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getcurrentprocess.aspx)
- [Assembly.GetEntryAssembly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the first answer. And for the second one, if I set that property, how should I write the path?

Comment: It would be good to know what type of project this is, to know in what environment you'll be accessing this image.

Comment: the basic windows form application

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: thank you for your help!